# Adding a UIPageControll to an UITableView Cell

Tags: iphone, uipagecontrol

i want to add a UIPageControl to a single tableView Cell. It should be possible to swipe the cell and indicate the position with a paged Controll.

The amound of Views within the paged controll is different in every cell. Is should also be possible if i scroll the table view that the actual view stays selected.

here is a screenshot which will tell you more than thousands words:
http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/889f10a5d9.png

has someone got an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like an awfully over-complicated design to me... but oh well.

Just remember that a table cell view is just a subclass of UIView. It's just used slightly differently to other view, eg. dequeuing resuable cells etc.

You should be able to add a scroll view as a subview of the table cell's contentView. Follow Apple's scroll view sample code to set up a pageable scroll view.

Comment: probably awful but for the usage of the app appropriate. Anyway: I tried it to implement but its not really easy. The detection of the gestures does not work at all. what i tried is to create a special UITableView Cell. In this i added an UIView which holds a scrollview and a pageControll. Within the scrollview i have several UIViews based on the data i get from a webservice. i ended up  with loading it but i the only thing which is recognized is the tap on the paged control.

Comment: The table view may be intercepting swipe gestures, in order to manage its own scrolling... I'm not entirely sure how to solve this. Since UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView, you're effectively putting a scroll view inside a scroll view (though, not directly). You could try playing around with setting the canCancelContentTouches and delayContentTouches property on both the table view and the scroll view in your cell and see where that gets you?